# PyQt5 QTabWidget: How to switch between tabs contained in classes and in the same window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I would like to switch tabs contained in their own classes when pushing a button (next/prior tabs). However, I cannot seem to do it. If I use self.tabs.show() I open a new window. However, I just want it to switch in the same window. Can you help me? Example code below.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QTabWidget, QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys

class Tab(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabContact(), "Contact Details")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabPeronsalDetails(), "Personal Details")
        vbox.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class TabContact(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pushButton = QPushButton("Go to next")
        pushButton.clicked.connect(self.nextTab)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(pushButton)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def nextTab(self):
        self.tabs = Tab()
        self.tabs.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


class TabPeronsalDetails(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pushButton_2 = QPushButton("Go to prior")
        pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.priorTab)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(pushButton_2)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def priorTab(self):
        self.tabs = Tab()
        self.tabs.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabdialog = Tab()
    tabdialog.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to change tabs from within `TabContact` or `TabPeronsalDetails`. This should be done from within `Tab` instead. In order for `Tab` to get access to the navigation buttons in `TabContact` and `TabPeronsalDetails` you need to make these buttons instance variables i.e.

```
class TabContact(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Go to next")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

class TabPeronsalDetails(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton("Go to prior")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
```

In `Tab` you can then connect an appropriate slot to the `clicked` signals of the buttons by doing something like

```
class Tab(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()

        contact = TabContact()
        personal_details = TabPeronsalDetails()

        self.tabWidget.addTab(contact, "Contact Details")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(personal_details, "Personal Details")

        vbox.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # connect slots to signals
        contact.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.next_tab)
        personal_details.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.prev_tab)

    def next_tab(self):
        cur_index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        if cur_index < len(self.tabWidget)-1:
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(cur_index+1)

    def prev_tab(self):
        cur_index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        if cur_index > 0:
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(cur_index-1)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot Heike. It makes a lot of sense.